# A bot that deletes all messages except for messeges saying "potato"

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a bot that only allows the messages saying, "potato" and deletes all other messages with different content. (I am very new to this stuff.)

Here is the code I've tried so far, created by a user here:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.content != "potato") return message.delete()
});
```

When I input it into the code, I get an indent error and a semi-colon error. When I auto fix them, I get this code:

```
    client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content != "potato") return message.delete();
});
```

The terminal repeats back the messages in the server (has no roles or perms), but doesn't delete them in discord if they aren't "potato". The bot has Admin perm.

Any edits or suggestions? (I do have a linter, not sure if relevant.)

Thanks, PM

Rest of code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('TOKEN');

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if(message.content !== "potato") return message.delete();
});
```

Comment: try using `message.content !== "potato"` instead of `message.content != "potato"`

Comment: Node shouldn't be giving an error for indentation or a semi colon in this scenario. My guess is that you have some malformed code, can you post more of the file?

Comment: @Spiralio Here is the rest:

`const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('TOKEN');

client.on("message", (message) => {
 if(message.content !== "potato") return message.delete();
});`

Comment: I'll edit into the question for better formatting.

Comment: The code you posted works just fine, I've tested it. Are you sure that's all your code? And why would the terminal repeat back the message? There is no `console.log` anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `await` before the `message.delete()` otherwise it won't work.
It's also better for code readability to put `client.login` at the bottom of the code.

Your code should look like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if(message.content !== "potato") {return await message.delete();}
});

client.login('TOKEN');
```

Comment: Calling the `delete()` method on the `message` will delete the message; there is absolutely no need to `await` here. Although it returns a promise, you don't use the returned value anywhere so OP's code will work fine.